# Source doesn't work in zsh (os x 10.12)

Tags: zsh

In bashrc case, I could be just input the source line like this,

> source /my/path/etc

As far as i know, zshrc also can input that line. but there was happen error.

> ERROR: geant4.sh could NOT self-locate GEANT4 installation
>
> This is most likely because you are using ksh, zsh or similar
>
> To fix this issue, cd to the directory containing this script
>
> and source it in that directory

And I can't understand last sentence starting for "To fix this issue",
If you have any idea, please tell me.

Comment: This seems to be more of a "some specific script cannot be sourced correctly because it cannot handle shells that are not bash well" than a "`source` doesn't work" thing. The error message seems to be pretty straight forward: Instead of sourcing the script (`geant4.sh`?) by path (e.g. `source /my/path/etc/geant4.sh`) change into the directory containing the script (`cd /my/path/etc`) and source it from there (`source geant4.sh`).

Comment: @Adaephon So,you mean, Instead of input the source line in my zshrc, go to directory containing the script and should source it when i always was open my terminal ?

Comment: @Adaephon Oh! It solved :) Thank you! now It works very well! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pushd` and `popd` to temporarily change directories within your `.zshrc` file (that's a rough explanation, see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands)).

To automatically source geant4.sh with zsh, add this line to your `.zshrc` file:

```
pushd /path/to/script >/dev/null; . /path/to/script/geant4.sh; popd >/dev/null
```

The `>/dev/null` is just directing the output to `null` so the sourcing doesn't cause anything to appear on your terminal when you open it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response :) Thank you for your reply!